# How do I make sure that my terminal opens the .firebaserc and firebase.json files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to learn how to write and deploy firebase cloud functions in firestore, but unlike the tutorials I follow, once I'm done with the "firebase init" command and the setup that follows in the terminal, the files I have mentioned, and the most important one, ie index.js, do not open up/show up automagically in Visual Studio Code. Does this mean I have done something wrong? Because the file *is* created, just not picked up by VSC immediately like it happens in every tutorial I have followed so far.

I have a secondary question too; but I will move it to another thread if someone tells me to.
Can I alter the state of my app (say, or instance, change the app's colour theme remotely) using cloud functions in firebase when im using Firestore?

I apologise for the noob questions, I have reviewed the docs and can't find a straight answer to either of my questions.

Thank you.